# How to refresh lib folder when update pom.xml?

Tags: intellij-idea

I create a simple sample Spring MVC project, where IntelliJ 14 by default generate a pom with

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
```

I change it to

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
```

and choose Maven -> Reimport, I can see the dependencies are downloaded to my local .m2 folder

However, when I expend lib folder, all dependencies stays with previous version:

[image]

How can I get the latest dependencies showing in \lib folder? I tried to synchronize current project, but it doesn't help this matter

## UPDATE

here is my maven setting
[image]

## UPDATE 2

I forget some detail, which is I create a Spring MVC project in the beginning(so I think it may not be a maven project at the moment), then I right click pom.xml and set current project to maven project.

So I think the jar files listed in \lib folder may be downloaeded via intellij for Spring MVC application, however when I set current project to maven project, it does not remove or update the jar file under the \lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

**1.** Choose menu `File \ Project Settings...`, In section `Build, Execution, Deployment \ Build Tools \ Maven \ Importing`, check `Import Maven projects automatically`. It means IntelliJ IDEA will **Synchronize Maven project model and IDEA project model each time when pom.xml is changed.**
[image]

**2.** Try closing project, restart IntelliJ IDEA, then reopen the project. 

**3.** Check your internet connection.

Comment: Thanks, but weird, the `Import Maven projects automatically` is already checked in my setting.

Comment: There are something wrong in your working environment, therefore you give section 2, 3 a chance to try. I am also use IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.3, and something have problem when slow internet connection, or many concurrent internet connections at same time.

Comment: I tried 2 & 3 but still the same. BTW, it looks u r using IntellJ on Ubuntu? Could u share any experience. i.e. performance, stability, any slowness? :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA in Windows 8.1. I also tried IntelliJ IDEA in Ubuntu in short time. I am very pleasure with this IDE.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ <s>isn't</s> shouldn't be looking there for your Maven project dependencies.  It <s>is</s> should be using the libraries and resources in your `.m2` directory instead.

Mind you, I've left those comments struck out on purpose; depending on your configuration, you may accidentally be doing that.

This is a picture of what the Dozer project looks like.  It's a Maven project which I cloned a ways back to see how it worked.

[image]

You're going to have to check your Project Structure (Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S) to ensure that the libraries that are coming through are prefixed with "Maven:".

If they are, then the files in your `lib` folder aren't being used by your project.

In all actuality, those are your global libraries (which you can also find under Project Structure > Global Libraries).  Any project has access to them.

If that's causing a conflict, consider deleting those JARs from your global libraries.  If you need them for another project, consider adding it to the project's *local* libraries instead.